# Issue with image upload using PHP and OLX API

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP script that uploads images to the OLX platform using their API. However, I'm encountering issues with the image upload functionality. I have followed the documentation provided by OLX, but the images are not being uploaded successfully.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// Include necessary libraries and setup variables
// Authenticate and get necessary data

// Creating new listing for OLX (successfully done) 
// Iterate over image URLs and attempt to upload them
foreach ($imageUrls as $imageUrl) {
    // Download the image
    // Prepare the image upload request
    // Send the request and handle the response
    // Clean up and proceed to the next image
}
```

The code logic involves downloading images from given URLs and then preparing the image upload request using the OLX API. However, the image upload is not working as expected, and I'm getting unexpected results.

I have confirmed that the image files are downloaded correctly and have verified that the necessary headers and request parameters are included in the API call. However, the response from the API is successful, and the images are not uploaded.
`var_dump($response);` -> this line of code returns this:

```
string(21) "{"message":"success"}"
```

I have also tried alternative approaches, such as directly sending the image contents or using different content types, but none of them have resolved the issue.

Could someone please review my code and provide guidance on what I might be missing or suggest any potential solutions? I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights into this problem.

And you can find their docs here: [Image-upload docs](https://api-documentation.olx.ba/listings#image-upload) .

Basically, everything goes smoothly, product is visible and everything else on the site, but image upload simply doesn't work (by that I mean image is not visible on the site) and I can't figure out what's problem.

Code:

```
    if (isset($res2_json['status']) && $res2_json['status'] === 'active') {
        $successCount++;
        echo "Product with SKU " . $product['sku'] . " published successfully.\n";
    
        // Get the image URLs from the payload
        $imageUrls = explode(',', $product['images']); // Split the image URLs into an array
    
        $uploadUrl = "https://api.olx.ba/listings/{$product_id}/image-upload";
    
        // Get the directory path of the PHP script file
        $scriptDirectory = dirname(__FILE__);
    
        // Create an array to hold the image files
        $imageFiles = array();
    
        // Iterate over each image URL and download them
        foreach ($imageUrls as $imageUrl) {
            $imageUrl = trim($imageUrl); // Remove any leading/trailing spaces from the URL
    
            // Download the image and save it locally in the same folder as the PHP script file
            $filename = basename($imageUrl);
            $localFilePath = $scriptDirectory . '/' . $filename;
            file_put_contents($localFilePath, file_get_contents($imageUrl));
    
            // Check if the image was saved successfully
            if (file_exists($localFilePath)) {
                // Create an array for each image with the required attributes
                $imageFile = array(
                    'name' => 'images[]',
                    'contents' => fopen($localFilePath, 'r'),
                    'filename' => $filename,
                );
    
                // Add the image file to the array
                $imageFiles[] = $imageFile;
            } else {
                echo "Failed to save image: {$imageUrl}\n";
            }
        }
    
        // Create the request body with the image files
        $requestBody = array('images' => $imageFiles);
    
        // Set the headers
        $headers11 = array(
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
            "OLX-CLIENT-ID: ",
            "OLX-CLIENT-TOKEN: "
        );
    
        // Create the stream context options
        $contextOptions = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => implode("\r\n", $headers11),
                'content' => $requestBody,
            ),
        );
    
        // Create the stream context
        $streamContext = stream_context_create($contextOptions);
    
        // Send the request
        $response = file_get_contents($uploadUrl, false, $streamContext);
    
        // Handle the image upload response as needed
        // For example, you can check the response status code to ensure the upload was successful
        if ($response !== false) {
            echo "Images uploaded successfully.\n";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to upload images.\n";
        }
        var_dump($response);
    
        // Delete the local image files
        foreach ($imageFiles as $imageFile) {
            $localFilePath = $scriptDirectory . '/' . $imageFile['filename'];
            unlink($localFilePath);
        }
    }                          
     else {
        $failureCount++;
        echo "Failed to publish product with SKU " . $product['sku'] . ".\n";
    }`
```

Update 19.06 (17:36) - by suggestion from comments I've refactured code to use cURL, didn't resolve the problem, same problem persist from earlier:

```
if (isset($res2_json['status']) && $res2_json['status'] === 'active') {
    $successCount++;
    echo "Product with SKU " . $product['sku'] . " published successfully.\n";

    // Get the image URLs from the payload
    $imageUrls = explode(',', $product['images']); // Split the image URLs into an array
    var_dump($imageUrls);
    $uploadUrl = "https://api.olx.ba/listings/{$product_id}/image-upload";

    // Get the directory path of the PHP script file
    $scriptDirectory = dirname(__FILE__);

    // Create an array to hold the image files
    $imageFiles = array();

    // Iterate over each image URL and download them
    foreach ($imageUrls as $imageUrl) {
        $imageUrl = trim($imageUrl); // Remove any leading/trailing spaces from the URL
        var_dump($imageUrls);
        // Download the image and save it locally in the same folder as the PHP script file
        $filename = basename($imageUrl);
        $localFilePath = $scriptDirectory . '/' . $filename;

        // Initialize cURL
        $ch = curl_init($imageUrl);

        // Set the cURL options for downloading the image
        $downloadOptions = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        );

        // Set the cURL options
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $downloadOptions);

        // Execute the request and get the image content
        $imageContent = curl_exec($ch);

        // Check for errors
        if ($imageContent === false) {
            echo "Failed to download image: {$imageUrl}. Error: " . curl_error($ch) . "\n";
            continue;
        }

        // Save the image content to a local file
        file_put_contents($localFilePath, $imageContent);

        // Check if the image was saved successfully
        if (file_exists($localFilePath)) {
            // Create an array for each image with the required attributes
            $imageFile = array(
                'name' => 'images[]',
                'contents' => fopen($localFilePath, 'r'),
                'filename' => $filename,
            );

            // Add the image file to the array
            $imageFiles[] = $imageFile;
        } else {
            echo "Failed to save image: {$imageUrl}\n";
        }

        // Close cURL
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    // Initialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the cURL options
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $uploadUrl,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
            "OLX-CLIENT-ID: ",
            "OLX-CLIENT-TOKEN: "
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $imageFiles
    );

    // Set the cURL options
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    // Send the request and capture the response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors
    if ($response === false) {
        echo "Failed to upload images. Error: " . curl_error($ch) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "Images uploaded successfully.\n";
        var_dump($response);
    }

    // Close cURL
    curl_close($ch);

    // Delete the local image files
    foreach ($imageFiles as $imageFile) {
        $localFilePath = $scriptDirectory . '/' . $imageFile['filename'];
        unlink($localFilePath);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 20.06 (as per suggestions from comments):**

1. The `$imageFiles` array is modified to store the image content directly, using the filename as the key. This is done by replacing the line:

   ```php
   $imageFile = array(
       'name' => 'images[]',
       'contents' => fopen($localFilePath, 'r'),
       'filename' => $filename,
   );
   ```

   with:

   ```php
   $imageFiles[$filename] = $imageContent;
   ```
2. The request body is created by JSON-encoding the `$imageFiles` array:

   ```php
   $requestBody = json_encode(array('images' => $imageFiles));
   ```
3. The `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option is set to the `$requestBody` instead of the `$imageFiles` array:

   ```php
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $requestBody
   ```
4. The file deletion in the `foreach` loop is updated to use the filename as the key in the `$imageFiles` array:

   ```php
   foreach ($imageFiles as $filename => $imageContent) {
       $localFilePath = $scriptDirectory . '/' . $filename;
       unlink($localFilePath);
   }
   ```

Comment: If you are uploading should `$response = file_get_contents` not be using `file_put_contents` or curl?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Before you edited comment, I have tried to `var_dump($imageUrls)` and I am getting array of links (which is right). Also when using `file_put_contents()` I am getting fatal error -> and as far as of my knowledge `file_put_contents()` function is not suitable for sending an HTTP request with a stream context.

Comment: `file_put_contents` will take a `context` argument but curl is far more powerful

Comment: Okay, let me try to rewrite my code using `cURL`, hopefully it will resolve my problem.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I've rewrited code with using cURL and I will update question in 1 second. Didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: You say you are getting `string(21) "{"message":"success"}"` when dumping the response, but according to https://api-documentation.olx.ba/listings#image-upload you should get an array of objects containing information about the uploaded images?

Comment: @CBroe You're right. It seems that there's a problem within my code, but I still can not figure out what's problem, because as far as I can see I adhere to their API Docs.

Comment: In the documentation they are using `Content-Type: application/json`, whereas you are sending `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. Does it say anywhere in the API documentation that you can also use the latter?

Comment: No, they didn't. I just reverted `Content-Type` header back from `multipart/form-data` to `application/json` - same problem is persisting, as well as response. @CBroe

Comment: _Just_ changing the header, doesn't change the format of the data you are actually sending. You will need to encode it as JSON yourself, cURL won't automatically do that for you. But `'contents' => fopen($localFilePath, 'r'),` can hardly be encoded as JSON, so I am not sure how you are actually supposed to send the image data. And the documentation doesn't appear to give any additional hints on that either, as far as I can see.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, you are right regarding docs they' didn't pay a lot of attention when writing it. I got the working example code few days ago from guy who is intended to do API support, the thing is that in example he provided they're using Guzzle - contacted their support via call tho, they are saying that he's currently sick and only guy who works on API part... In that example he's providing file names, e.g. "test-pic.jpg"...  [https://i.imgur.com/QRC22bY.png](Code Example Look Here)

Comment: The actual file content gets read with `file_get_contents` there, so that is what you will also need to do - pass the actual _content_ of the file. (And that Guzzle code _is_ sending a `multipart/form-data` request, so apparently you don't _have to_ send JSON.)

Comment: @CBroe I've done changes to the code, again getting the same response - I've updated the question with the changes made by the way, can you look at it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to say that I've fixed the problem successfully after deciding to go with Guzzle.

I had to completely refactor the code, but it's fine. Also, I've made decision to go with Bearer token at the end, because I found it more suitable.

```
if (isset($res2_json['status']) && $res2_json['status'] === 'active') {
            $successCount++;
            echo "Product with SKU " . $product['sku'] . " published successfully.\n";

            // Get the image URLs from the payload
            $imageUrls = explode(',', $product['images']); // Split the image URLs into an array

            // Prepare the image upload URL
            $uploadUrl = "https://api.olx.ba/listings/{$product_id}/image-upload";

            // Create a Guzzle client instance
            $client = new Client();

            // Create an array to hold the image files
            $imageFiles = [];

            // Iterate over each image URL and upload them
            foreach ($imageUrls as $imageUrl) {
                $imageUrl = trim($imageUrl);

                // Send a GET request to download the image
                $response = $client->get($imageUrl);

                // Get the image content from the response
                $imageContent = $response->getBody()->getContents();

                // Append the image to the image files array
                $imageFiles[] = [
                    'name' => 'images[]',
                    'contents' => $imageContent,
                    'filename' => basename($imageUrl)
                ];
            }

            try {
                // Send a POST request using Guzzle
                $response = $client->request('POST', $uploadUrl, [
                    'multipart' => $imageFiles,
                    'headers' => [
                        'Authorization' => '',
                    ],
                ]);

                echo "Images uploaded successfully.\n";
                var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Failed to upload images. Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            }
        } else {
            $failureCount++;
            echo "Failed to publish product with SKU " . $product['sku'] . ".\n";
        }
```